# Use ONVIF to determine if a camera supports dewarping

Tags: onvif

Using ONVIF, how can I determine if the device has a fisheye camera and subsequently if it supports dewarping stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ONVIF, For any feature to be confirmed as supported by the device  usually can be done in one or more ways (including but not limited to the list) listed below

1. Reading the device/service capabilities using GetServiceCapabilities interface provided by every service
2. Reading the configurations provided by device using 'Get[entity]Configurations' interface
3. Reading the configuration parameter options using Get[entity]ConfigurationOptions interface

The "entity" varies depends on the feature, Check the entities list here

- https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/media/ONVIF-Media2-Service-Spec.pdf Section 4.1 Media profile)

For your query about dewarp feature support, option 2 has to be checked. So you have to read VideoSourceConfiguration from the device via 'GetVideoSourceConfiguration' interface and check the response.

The response from device shall adhere to the specification as quoted below

Ref: https://www.onvif.org/specs/srv/media/ONVIF-Media2-Service-Spec-v1712.pdf

- Section : 5.2.2 Video source configuration

  - View Mode

    - **Fisheye – Undewarped viewmode from a device supporting fisheye lens**
    - **Dewarp – Dewarped view mode for device supporting fisheye lens**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @JimUdall please mark/accept the response as answer so that this thread can be closed.